# tar returns 1 in script, but not interactively

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, tar

If I run the following shell script 
(ie tar file then delete source if it is successful)

```
#!/bin/bash
tar cvf /home/acampton/vortex_data/2014-02-14/tmp-2014-02-14-test2.tar -C /home/acampton/vortex_data/2014-02-14 SIC_17_RADAR-2014-02-14_all_no_dups.csv
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
then
 echo "Deleting files - tar successful ($?) at time "`date`
else
 echo "Not Deleting files - tar unsuccessful ($?) at time "`date`
fi
```

it returns 1 (= Source file being changed while archived)

```
acampton@ALIEN:~/work/spm$ ./v1.sh
SIC_17_RADAR-2014-02-14_all_no_dups.csv
Not Deleting files - tar unsuccessful (1) at time Tue Feb 18 10:38:16 EST 2014
```

But if I run it interactively, it works (every time!)

```
acampton@ALIEN:~/work/spm$ tar cvf /home/acampton/vortex_data/2014-02-14/tmp-2014-02-14-test2.tar -C /home/acampton/vortex_data/2014-02-14 SIC_17_RADAR-2014-02-14_all_no_dups.csv
SIC_17_RADAR-2014-02-14_all_no_dups.csv
acampton@ALIEN:~/work/spm$ echo $?
0
acampton@ALIEN:~/work/spm$
```

And I can guarantee that the source is not being modified when I run the script (or interactively)

Ive also tried using --exclude=everything_else_but_my_file and get the same thing

Note am NOT trying to tar up . (which usually gives the "File changed as we read it" cause its trying to tar up its own .tar file)

At the end of my rope - looking at alternatives to tar, but need to know why this is happening so I can sleep at night

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's up with the trailing `"` character in the script (first line after the shebang)?

Comment: By the way, it's unidiomatic to explicitly test `$?` for zero-vs-nonzero state when avoidable. Better to do `if tar ...; then echo "tar was successful"; else echo "tar failed"; fi` -- and let the `if` implicitly check tar's exit status.

Comment: Sorry cut and paste error, on the " - fixed it

Comment: Also, you can't trust `$?` to stay consistent. As soon as you do another command (like the `[ $? -ne 0 ]`), then `$?` has *that* command's exit status, not tar's. If you want to be able to look at tar's exit status more than once, you need to assign it to a variable; as it is, your error message saying tar is unsuccessful will **always** report 1, no matter which nonzero exit status is actually in use.

Comment: Also, don't end your double-quotes before calling `date` -- it makes the shell do extra work (as it needs to string-split and glob-expand the results of unquoted expansions).

Comment: I realise now my logic was inverted (ie delete if -eq, not -ne) and so does that mean "if [ $? -ne 0 ]" was false, which turn $? to 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

The `if` condition is backwards. 0 means success, non-zero means failure. Use `-eq` instead of `-ne`. Also you've got an extra `then` in there.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
 echo "Deleting files - tar successful ($?) at time "`date`
else
 echo "Not Deleting files - tar unsuccessful ($?) at time "`date`
fi
```

Actually, the idiomatic way to test if a command succeeded is to put it right in the `if` statement.

```
if tar cvf /home/acampton/vortex_data/2014-02-14/tmp-2014-02-14-test2.tar -C /home/acampton/vortex_data/2014-02-14 SIC_17_RADAR-2014-02-14_all_no_dups.csv; then
 echo "Deleting files - tar successful ($?) at time $(date)"
else
 echo "Not Deleting files - tar unsuccessful ($?) at time $(date)"
fi
```

Comment: yeah sorry , extra then aint really there (am copying from another computer)

Comment: Good pickup, but why was it printing (1) as $?

Comment: Also does that mean $? might be coming from the `date` command in the echo

Comment: @user3321283: the `$?` value of 1 was coming from `[ $? -ne 0 ]` -- the test failed, so it returned 1 as its exit code. That was the last command execute before the `echo ...` command was parsed, so that's the exit status that `$?` fetched. Putting `tar` directly in the `if` command solves this problem. The other option would be to use something like `tarstatus=$?` immediately after the `tar ...` command, then use `$tarstatus` for all further testing/printing/etc.